# Can't navigate to url in Google Chrome Android Emulator, just says Data;,

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, android-studio, automation, appium

I am using eclipse, Appium 1.6.4 and Android Studion with Android 7.0 also tried with 6.0.

I run my automated test and it executes, it connects to the device, it opens the chrome browser but then doesnt navigate to the google url using the driver.get(...) method it just says data;, . I dont get any errors until it eventually times out and tries running it again.

Any help would be appreciated as ive tried a few things and got nothing.

Thank you.